# SQL Sample Function Seems to be returning more than the specific percentage

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sample

I am trying to assign a control status of true to 10% of distinct groups in my table. Everything runs fine, but when I view the results, the percentages are way off. I'm getting more like 1/3 of records with the true control status, instead of the desired 10%. I've been using sample based on the distinct group id, but please let me know if something looks off here. Thanks!

PS: This is SQL Snowflake

Code and results listed below :

```
update table 
    set control_status=true
    where group_id in
       (select DISTINCT(group_id) from table sample(10));

update table 
    set control_status=false
    where control_status is null;


select control_status, count(distinct(group_id)),count(distinct(person_id)), count(control_status) from table group by control_status;
```

Results

| control_status | count(distinct(group_id)) | count(distinct(person_id)) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| True | 50,000 | 100,000 |
| False | 100,000 | 200,000 |

Comment: why do you sample anyway if you want exact values anyway? sample chooses randowmly values

Comment: I am specifically looking for random values actually. We want the control value assigned to a random 10% of groups

Comment: so you select random data, ok, you get them and you compare them to excat data?, changing the sampe data, will produce different results anytime you run it, so the comparision makes no sense. even checking two runs would result in dfferent results depemnding on the data

Comment: Well, what I'm trying to do is update the table with the random values and then just pull the results to see what they are after they've been set. If the update was supposed to set 10% of groups with a certain value, I wouldn't expect it to be so far off that I'm seeing 33% of groups with the new true value. Where are you seeing a comparison with exact data? I'm not comparing to anything, just looking at the output and seeing if it approximately matches what I would expect based on the query.

Comment: random and stochastic doen't work that way, even with a coin or a dice.  lets say you have 100 throws of a coin, you would expect a 50 50 of both sides, but that isn't true, the numbers are equal, so when you now take 10 % of that data, you get (i reduce the number to get my point)  4 posibilities  all one side all the other side 50:50 70:30 (and so on), you can't really tell from one result, if the coin had on both sides the same..... you should read a book about stochastic to get a better understanding

Comment: Right, I'm familiar with all that, but with increasingly large sample sizes, the data typically approached the expected distribution. So if you flip a coin one million times and take a truly random 10% of those results, you'd expect the sample to reflect the true 50/50 probability. Likewise, I would expect a sample that says 10% to return somewhere near 10 percent when the population is extremely large.

Comment: Do you have a better way you would recommend achieving the solution I'm looking for here? How to assign a value to approximately 10% of the distinct groups?

Comment: no, when you toss teh coin it can be that it get always the same side, the same goes for sample data, you can't expect nothing as they are random

Comment: i really can't say take the data from the sample make a exact count, i don't know what you want too achieve. as i said, there are courses at university, at least where i studied, that handle that .

Comment: All I want to achieve is to take a random 10% of the records and update them with a certain value. That's got to be possible? If not the sample function, maybe incorporating random or something else, but the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/sample.html) for sample specifically says "each row has a 10% probability of being included in the sample" which again, for millions of records seems like it should output approximately 10% of the records being updated. It doesn't need to be exact, just close.

Comment: Could I maybe select top 10% and order by random? I'm not sure what the syntax exactly would be

Comment: I've run this same code several times to test it the randomness of the sample, and it's outputting approximately the same 1/3 ratio every time which really seems like somethings wrong with the way I've structured the code, not the sampling itself

Comment: Can we rephrase the question in terms of your goals - maybe we have an alternative approach without using `SAMPLE()`

Comment: Yes, thanks Felipe! Happy to use another approach. I am just wanting to take a random 10% of groups and assign them a control status of true

Comment: I think those of us reading this are trying to understand the overall goal of what you're trying to do with this data, not necessarily the approach that you've laid out.  Is there a ERD / hierarchy in your data that you can describe that pertains to groups and person IDs? How many distinct groups do you have in your data?  Is the control status intended to be persistent?  Will you run this query repeatedly on the same data set?  Does it matter if the group is already tagged as TRUE with respect to control status?

Comment: "All I want to achieve is to take a random 10% of the records and update them with a certain value" ... I think the problem here is that you're not updating those records chosen, but you're updating *all* the records associated with the Group_ID of the records chosen in the sample - which also includes Person_ID records you didn't choose but are associated with the Group_ID of a record you did chose.  From above I gather that there's a 1-many relationship of Person_IDs to Group_IDs

Comment: Just a sense check, but you are running `set control_status=false` before running the code above? If not then you might be looking at records that were set to true by some earlier update, as well as those updated by the query above.

Comment: To Jim: there is a many to one with many persons at the same group. The control status needs to be at the group level. There are about 100m distinct groups to the 400m distinct people. The control status is designed to be persistent and not rerun/reapplied later. Control status is a new field so at the start of the run, it won't be filled with anything

Comment: I do want to update all the records associated, even if they have persons. That's kind of the point. The groups will be assigned to the control status and then the people at those groups will also have a control status

Comment: And to Nathan, yeah I actually dropped the whole column and readded it before rerunning this query to test the % assignment. It's a new field, so no carry over from a historical situation

Comment: Have you reviewed my answer below?  The assignment would be at the group_id level.  Is the distribution of people to groups homogenous (meaning, each distinct group has the same or similar number of persons in each group)?

Comment: Ah! No, I didn't see your response until just this moment. That is exactly the solution I was looking for and is now outputting an approximate 10% like I was looking for. Thank you so much for your help. Although to be honest, I am still struggling a bit to understand why this requires that additional select statement.

Comment: You want 10% of the distinct groups, not the groups associated with 10% of the people …. The latter likely returns more distinct groups than you want, which is why you end up having a larger control group than desired.

Comment: Right, but what's strange is even with my previous method, it still wasn't 10% of people. It  was coming out to about 33% of distinct people as well. I don't want to look this gift horse in the mouth, but do wish I better understood why the different approach did the trick

Comment: Build up the query one component at a time.  What does select person_id from table sample(10) show you?  Should be 10% of the rows in the table.  Are person_id's unique, or are there duplicates of them in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the following - you need to create a representative set of the distinct group_ids in order to chose 10% of those and not be skewed by the rows in the underlying table that pertain to people who have a 1-M relationship with group_id:

```
update table_name 
    set control_status=true
    where group_id in
       (select group_id from (select distinct (group_id) from table_name) x sample(10));
```

The rest remains the same as your original post:

```
update table 
    set control_status=false
    where control_status is null;


select control_status, count(distinct(group_id)),count(distinct(person_id)), count(control_status) from table group by control_status;
```